# Django custom form attrs removes css class

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm dealing with an RTL `CharField` so I impelemted the below in my `admin.py`:

```
class CustomPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'lead', 'body', 'status', 'is_featured']
        widgets = {'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'dir': 'rtl'})}


@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomPostForm
```

This works fine except that when I look at the form in the Admin site the width of the RTL field is less than the next LTR field:

[image]

And if I remove the whole custom form, then both fields look the same:

[image]

So I inspect the code and realize that the `slug` field has a `css` class called `vTextField` and if I change the custom form's `attrs` both fields look the same:

```
widgets = {'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'dir': 'rtl', 'class': 'vTextField'})}
```

So my question is, is it normal or intentional for Django to remove CSS class if `attrs` is used and my approach in putting the class back is correct, or I'm missing something here?

Comment: I would think that this is something the CSS stylesheet is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing attrs `{'class': 'vTextField'}` with `{'dir': 'rtl'}`. So yes, original attrs is replaced with yours. It's normal and expected.

Add the attribute inside init method:

```
class CustomPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'lead', 'body', 'status', 'is_featured']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].widget.attrs['dir'] = 'rtl'
```